# Which is a stronger visual indicator for depth

Tags: design-principles

**Which "effect" is a greater visual indicator for a line which looks to be travelling into the screen?** A color gradient, or greater to narrower width (starting at full width on the bottom and narrowing as the top approaches)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends upon surrounding objects.

However, I'd say that the foreshortening will convey depth a bit more than a gradient.